# Animation Keyframes only appear in "NonLinear Animation" window

Tags: animation

Only just starting to learn blender animation so I'm trying to follow some basic tutorials with the FBX I'm using for my game in unity.

I was looking at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C2ClFO3FAY

But when I perform the steps to add a keyframe, neither the dope sheet, nor the timeline populate. The keyframe does get added somewhere though, since my character still moves when scrubbing between frames. Eventually I found them in the "Nonlinear animation" window. So of course I started trying to figure out what that even is which led me down a whole different rabbit hole in which most people don't actually understand what it is either. So I tried to learn more about "NLA" which is... at least related if not the nonlinear animation window itself?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SQdHehksJw&feature=share

But now I'm even more confused because the keyframes still appear on the dope sheet and everything just fine for this guy. Just not for me.

I'll be honest in that Blender is probably the most complex program I've ever tried to use for animation. Akeytsu, UMotion and Unity itself were far more straightforward. I would love to get this to be at least somewhat closer to the workflow I'm used to.

My steps:
Open new blender file
Import FBX
Open Animation tab
Select 1st frame in dopesheet/timeline/whatever
Rotate bone
click I => create keyframe (want to be more specific but now the I key doesn't bring up any prompt wth!)
Notice no new keyframes in any window except "Nonlinear Animation"

Version: 2.81a

Comment: Hi & welcome. Made gif for https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208471/15543  which I believe shows what to do. Click on action in NLA to select, TAB to edit, (turns green (in my theme)) and puts the action  "in the slot". Once in the slot can add keyframes as expected.

Comment: Okay I clicked the action, pressed Tab and it turned green. But keyframes didn't appear in the action editor like in your gif. I see them just above the action in the NLA window but if I try to interact with them at all, it stops "editing" the action and it turns orange again.

Comment: please share a (small and simple) file with your problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure thing: https://pasteall.org/blend/c1305422cbb64969bffc7688df1e6c48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter how many times I re-did all the steps the other day, it just would not work at all. Today everything seems fine and I've done absolutely nothing different.

Blender sure is a mystery ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Having the same issue.